# Manipulating hidden div's

Tags: jquery, html, dom-manipulation

Ok, so i have a few `<div1>` elements with static content inside of them.  Then if you hover over the `<div1>` another `<div2>` pops up over top of it. (note: how this happens is the "display" property changes from "none" to "block")  This `<div2>` has data that is relevant to `<div1>`.  It populates dynamically based on the `<div1>` that you over on.

These `<div>` elements i do not have access to manipulate.  What i am trying to do is create a JQuery script that says if ***this*** particular data is populated into the `<div2>` than manipulate it in ***this*** way.

Could someone please help me with this?  I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks!

If you have any questions or anything please let me know!

EDITED:
Ok, here is what i have... `<div id="model-rotator-form">` is the div that stays hidden until you hover over an "li", then it displays with dynamic content.

Within this `<div>` is an H2 element that holds the vehicle name, a UL element that holds two link images, and a bunch of other elements that i'm not trying to change.

The H2 element is `<h2 class="model-name">Vehicle Name</h2>` and the UL element is `<ul class="link-btn"><li><a class="linkBtn" href="Model.aspx?d=711" id="model-rotator-link-1">Research</a></li><li><a class="linkBtn" href="/Dallas/For-Sale/New/Volkswagen/Jetta SportWagen/" id="model-rotator-link-2">Inventory</a></li></ul>`

My code right now doesn't work i know...this is just a reference point...
`$('#model-rotator-form *');
if($('$h2.model-name').length() >= 25){
$('ul.link-btn').css('margin-top','-20px');
}`

Let me know what i can do.  Again...hope this code helps.

Comment: -1 for not giving any sample code

Comment: i'm sorry, i usually give sample code if i had it...problem is i have no sample code.  I'll try and write out an example...

Comment: For now, here's a URL with the problem area.  http://mckinneyvw.com/  Look at the model gallery and when you hover on a car the div pops up.  Notice how the one on the right has a long name that is wrapping and making the rest of the content push down too far.  I'd like to add a conditional statement to the element that holds the name to say if there are more than 25 characters, then add some css styling to the element that holds the links below the image to move them up a bit.  Hope this helps...you can also use firebug on the website i provided.

Comment: Shifting things around based on character count is usually unreliable and, I suspect that there may be a purely CSS solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that a code sample is provide, I'm rewriting my original answer.

So something like this might work for you, in the function that pops the div (and has the popped div active in "this") ...

if ( $(this).find(".model-name").text().length > 25 )
   $(this).find(".link-button").addClass("whatever");

The "whatever" class might have a negative margin that moves it a bit higher up.  You're getting into hard-coding territory here, though, where you're making specific pixel decisions  within the code, which is a bit scary

Comment: Ok, i think this helps me out. - testing it now

Comment: i tried this...

$('#model-rotator ul li.model-flow-item').hover(function()
{
if($('#model-rotator-form').find('h2.model-name').text().length > 25 ){ $('#model-rotator-form').find('ul.link-btn').css('margin-top','0px');
}
});

This is setting every LI item to have a margin-top of 0px, not just the ones that have names longer than 25 characters.  What could be my problem.  Could it be that this script is running before the fields populates the new dynamic vehicle name? So it is not actually counting the new characters?

Comment: $('#model-rotator ul li.model-flow-item').hover(function() { if($(this).find('h2.model-name').text().length > 25 ){ $(this).find('ul.link-btn').css('margin-top','0px'); } });

Comment: (this) works on the CURRENT pop-out, by simply using the ID, it works globally.  Is this a shared pop-out that gets constantly changed with new content, or a specific pop-out for each hover image?  If it's separate the above code will work.  If it's a shared one, then you'll want to reset the .css() after you close the pop out.

Comment: It is shared.

The above code is not working.  The reason is that the hidden div that pops out is not inside of the <div id='#model-rotator'>.  So (this) won't work, right?

Comment: <div id="#model-rotator"> and <div id="model-rotator-form"> are siblings in the hierarchy of the code

Comment: Ok, this works...now i just have to remove the class on "mouseout"...I think i can handle this part.   Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're right, since its shared and a sibling, $(this) is incorrect.  What I would do is ensure that you can even get the length.  When that box pops, can you just alert( $("h2.model-name").length ) to ensure that we're in the right ballpark?  Assuming so, you should then be able to assign a new/proper class to ul.link-btn based on the length or size of that H2

Comment: This code actually works...

$('#model-rotator ul li.model-flow-item').hover(
  function() {
    if($(this).find('span.vehicle-info strong').text().length > 25 ){
      $('#model-rotator-form').find('ul.link-btn').css('margin-top','0px');
    }else if($(this).find('span.vehicle-info strong').text().length < 25 ){
      $('#model-rotator-form').find('ul.link-btn').css('margin-top','20px');
 }
}
);